# Node.js EventLoop operation Not completing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, mongodb

*This regards a  Node/Express/MongoDB app, with an AJAX call*

> For some reason, a `selector.html(`) event was replacing the html of the
>   selector, but now it is not.

**The only change was the introduction of an `editAll()` function in the backend, which passes the MongoDB data on `.get`, to make some calculations before delivering it to the frontend over ajax.**

*Instead of the browser-console writing `GET http://localhost:9999/` with each `btn.click`*

```
[13:47:57.240] GET http://localhost:9999/ [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 5ms]
[13:47:57.174] "Getting All Actions"
[13:47:57.192] "value of action with index 0 = 4"
[13:47:57.193] "value of action with index 1 = 8"
[13:47:57.193] "value of action with index 2 = 9"
[13:48:03.704] GET http://localhost:9999/ [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 7ms]
[13:48:03.640] "Getting All Actions"
[13:48:03.661] "value of action with index 0 = 4"
[13:48:03.661] "value of action with index 1 = 8"
[13:48:03.661] "value of action with index 2 = 9"
```

> **..the console writes a full set of 'responses', for a set of *repetitive* divs that appear on the frontend**

```
[13:29:24.244] GET http://localhost:9999/ [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 5ms]
[13:29:24.182] "Getting All Actions"
[13:29:24.197] "value of doc with index 0 = 24"
[13:29:24.197] "value of doc with index 1 = 28"
[13:29:24.197] "value of doc with index 2 = 29"
...
[13:29:24.198] "value of doc with index 6 = 24"
[13:29:24.198] "value of doc with index 7 = 28"
[13:29:24.199] "value of doc with index 8 = 29"
```

The backend is working perfectly, as far as I can tell because the only `3 docs in the db` are passed to the eventAll() function, which delivers the same `3 docs` again.

```
function getAll(res) {

    db.collection('demo').find().sort( { value: 1 } ).toArray(function (err, docs) {
        console.log("Got the docs: " + utils.inspect(docs));

        //res.json({docs: docs}); THIS WORKS PERFECTLY,
                                  but the eventAll() pass causes this frontend issue

            /* pass and rebuild the data array before we 'json' it */
        var editedDocs = editAll(docs); 
        res.json({docs: editedDocs});

    });
}
```

**With the editAll() function called to pass data, is the eventloop operation not ending or something?**

```
function editAll(allDocs) {
  var returnedValue = [];
  for (var i=0, len=allDocs.length; i < len; ++i){
      //does some calculations
    var newVal = {_id:allDocs[i]._id,title:allDocs[i].title,value:allDocs[i].value};
    returnedValue.push(newVal);
  }
  console.log(returnedValue);
  return (returnedValue);
}
```

**Why for every `btn.click` is another set of divs being added to `#result`**

Here's the ajax .get call that builds some html on btn.click, via gotAllSuccess

```
$('#getBtn').click(function() {
  console.log('Getting All');
  $.get('http://localhost:9999').
   done(gotAllSuccess).
   fail(gotAllFailure);
});

function gotAllSuccess(result){

  var docs = result.docs;
  var html = '';
  var doc;
  for (var i=0, len=docs.length; i < len; i++){
    doc = docs[i];
        console.log("value of doc with index " + i + " = " + doc.value);
    html += "<div class='rResult' id='rResult" + i + "'>"+doc.title+"</div><br>";
  }
  $('#result').html(html);
}
```

Comment: First, you should check what number of docs you get after `editDocs` call.
Can you rephrase your question? It is barely readable.
For the first glance I cannot see ay issues with your code.

Comment: @Mr_Mig am checking now, and will rephrase the question right afterwards.. Thanks for the comment

Comment: @Mr_Mig updated the question, is it clearer? Only 3 docs exist before and after the editAll() call, but they're printed Over-And-Over, on.btn.click, in the frontend!

Comment: still I have some additional questions:
  1. what is logged inside `editAll` function just before return statement?
  2. Is that all logic you have in your editAll function?

Comment: 1. The returnedValue array is logged in the editAll() function, matching exactly what was passed from the db.  2. At this moment, for testing purposes, this is all the logic in the editAll() function.. there will be some calculations once this is working (one step at a time ;)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, your code is OK and must work as intended. 
I would suggest you to check the logic and to log `editedDocs` value just before writing it to the response.

It seems that somehow you queries results are **buffered**.

You can rewrite the `editAll` function as follows (to eliminate the loop and all additional variables, and all possible **side effects**):

```
function editAll(allDocs) {
    return allDocs.map(function(it){
        return { 
            _id:it._id,
            title:it.title,
            value:it.value 
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: logging the editedDocs value shows that on each btn.click, the length of the value increases by the number of docs in the db (3)..?

Comment: Do you have `editedDocs` or `returnedDocs` declared anywhere upper in the code (in the outer scope)?